# SSRS Subscription Error: Failure sending mail: Report processing has been canceled by the user. Mail will not be resent

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

On the report Subscriptions page, under "Status" for Last Run, it has the following error:
"Failure sending mail: Report processing has been canceled by the user. Mail will not be resent".

It's a subscription, no person canceled this. Maybe there is a problem with a service.

I would really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

In doing some googling, it would seem like there's an error during the report or subscription processing that occurs outside SSRS. From SSRS's perspective then, it appears that the user/agent that initiated the subscription stopped it.

A couple of things to do:

1. Before wasting a bunch of time, look through the logs and see if you can isolate the exact error.
2. Try to run the report in BIDS or Report Builder and make sure it runs successfully. If it's a data-driven subscription, make sure that query runs properly.
3. When a subscription is created, the Windows account used when the subscription was created is treated as the author/owner of that subscription. If the person that created the subscription has since had permission revoked, that may be causing the problem. More information on this issue [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/miah/2008/07/10/tip-change-the-owner-of-sql-reporting-services-subscription/).
4. Consider increasing the timeout settings for this specific report in the subscription settings.

That's all I can think of. Respond via comment if you have questions.